# How to securely set up continuous delivery?

Tags: automation, travis-ci, circleci, continuous-delivery, semaphore-ci

**Setup:**

- Private master repo and every developer has their own private fork.
- Currently using CircleCI, but we'd be happy to switch to satisfy requirements
- Branches on master repo are protected with merge restrictions

**Requirements:**

- Build + test on forked pull requests
- Deploy to different environments based on master repo branch updates
- Not all developers can be fully trusted with production credentials

**Partial Solution:**

- Enable building and passing secrets on forked pull requests ([Reference](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009201414))
- Use CircleCI contexts to set environment variables per branch. This allows different deploy targets.

**Problems:**

- All repo specific secrets as well as all global contexts are now accessible by anyone who can open a PR.
- Even if we disable building on forked pull requests, anyone with write access to at least one repo can access all global contexts.

**Question:**

- This would seems to be a very common use case. How do other companies solve it?
- Is CircleCI not the right tool for this? - *No, it is not (see below).*
- Should we build a custom solution?

---

**Edit1:**

CircleCI got back to me and surprisingly this is not a use case they support. Looking into other providers now. Above questions are still unanswered.

---

**Edit2:**

I've also contacted TravisCi and SemaphoreCi and it appears that only TravisCi supports building forked PRs and not leaking secrets into them ([Reference](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/#pull-requests-and-security-restrictions)).

SempahoreCi is missing (1) building forked PRs and (2) hiding secrets from the deployment phase in non-master workflows

CircleCi has [restricted contexts](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/#running-workflows-with-a-restricted-context), but they would require manually changing workflows. Definitely not easy to set up and I don't fully understand how they would work.